# Can we Automatically Restart the Telgram bot(Python) once it is stopped on server using Deamonize or something else?

Tags: python, server, telegram-bot

- So i have created a **telegram bot** in python.
- It is run by its **main.py** file.
- It is running on the **server**.
- But sometimes it stops **Due to internet** or some minor issue.
- Can there be code which can automatically restart the the main.py code on server maybe using **Deamonize library**.
- If Yes,please suggest how to do

Thank YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Linux, you can use crontab

crontab is used for scheduling event